# Google Endpoints API Authentication to other APIs

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I am creating an API using Google Cloud Endpoints, which needs to use the Google Drive API on the backend.  I am able to require an authenticated user by adding a User parameter like so:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "folders.get", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public Folder getFolder(@Named("id") String id, User user) throws NotFoundException, ForbiddenException, BadRequestException {


    if (user == null) {
        throw new ForbiddenException("You must authenticate to use this API.");
    }

    Drive service = Utils.createDriveFromUser(user);
```

The problem comes in when I try to make requests to other Google APIs using the user parameter.

`createDriveFromUser` is essentially the stock OAuth sample code:

```
    AuthorizationCodeFlow authFlow = Utils.initializeFlow();
    Credential credential = authFlow.loadCredential(user.getUserId());
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(Utils.HTTP_TRANSPORT,
                Utils.JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
```

The above code works for making requests following the "normal" OAuth flow.  I have a servlet which runs that method and is able to successfully make authenticated calls to the Drive API.  When I try testing my API method, however, I get a 403:

```
{
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "reason" : "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
}
```

Because of the way that endpoints authentication works on the local dev server (always returning the example@example.com user instead of a user I could actually make real API calls with) I have been deploying the application to test it.  If there's a better way I'm all ears, that workflow sucks.

What am I missing with the authentication within an endpoints API?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the appropriate scopes, audiences and clientId's on your ApiMethod annotation.

Also, are you testing your app on localhost?

Per cloud endpoint OAuth [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/), It seems that the user on dev server is "User object with email set to "example@example.com" and user ID set to 0 regardless of whether or not a valid OAuth request was made"

Comment: Do the scopes need to also go on the ApiMethod if they're declared in Api declaration?  I currently have:

@Api(name = "gyfp", version = "v1", scopes = {Constants.Scope.USER_EMAIL, Constants.Scope.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY})

Comment: Api annotation doc - "if you do define more than one scope, note that the scope check will pass if the token is minted for any of the specified scopes. To override the scopes specified here for a particular API method, specify different scopes in the @ApiMethod annotation". That may not be the desired outcome if using more than one scope.

Comment: ohhhhh okay, that makes sense.  So I should probably keep the USER_EMAIL scope at the API level, and then require the actual google drive scopes on the methods that need them so that they will be required and not satisfied by the USER_EMAIL scope.  Thanks, I will try that

Comment: The saga continues... I tried changing around the scopes and now user is null.  I also tried combining multiple required scopes into one by joining them with spaces, but that also didn't appear to work.  Thanks for the help thus far! :)

Comment: I had encountered the null user problem when the method was "post" on the annotation and the client called using '"get". Once I sync'd the two, the user on dev machine is passed with id 0 as stated in the doc.

Comment: Interesting.  For now I'm just using the API explorer to test things which should be using the appropriate request method

Comment: Any luck implementing this successfully? I ran into this same problem, but didn't find any solution.